# How should I understand "> outfile 2>&1" and " 2>&1 > outfile"?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

I cannot understand the difference between these two cases:

1. `./a.out > outfile 2>&`

   I can see both standard output and error output in outfile
2. `./a.out 2>& > outfile`

   I can only see standard output int outfile, and error output was printed on the screen

How should I understand this?
I think they are the same!

Comment: See e.g. [a shell manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), they explain it well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: While your comment is probably not wrong, it seems mildly cruel to point at a dense, unindexed 5MB+ text document and say "it's somewhere in there, why didn't you see it"...

Comment: @KerrekSB Well at the top there is a link to a section called [REDIRECTION](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION), shouldn't be that hard to find. Unless one doesn't know that what's happening above is redirection.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Why not add the fragment identifier to the link? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I was about to, but got distracted. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`n> file` creates/truncates `file` and associates it to file descriptor `n`.  If `n` is not specified, `1` (i.e. standard output) is assumed.

`n>&m` copies (using [`dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)) file descriptor `m` onto `n`.

So if you write `./a.out 2>& >outfile`, then the standard output descriptor is first copied onto the stderr descriptor, and then stdout is redirected to outfile.

You can see those redirection operators as assignments if you like:

- `2>& >file`  would be read as `fd2 := fd1; fd1 := "file"`, which is not the same as
- `>file 2>&`  which is `fd1 := "file"; fd2 := fd1`

Comment: @adl what does ":=" stand for? and why the direction is not the same?

Comment: @JasonYang `x := y` stands for *assign `y` to `x`*  (as in ALGOL, Smalltalk, Pascal, Ada, OCaml, Eiffel, VHDL...  all these languages agreed that since assignment was not a symmetric operation, it should not have a symmetric symbol).  The direction is precisely the point here: it's the same, you always assign from right to left. `2>&1` means copy fd1 onto fd2, it's read from right to left.

Comment: @adl Seems I mix those two concept: 2>&1 should understand as redirect fd1 to fd2,but should read as let fd1 := fd2. When we say redirect, the direction is from left to right,but when we say assign,it should read from right to left. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Redirections are applied in order. In `2>&1 > file`, first `stderr` is replaced with a copy of `stdout`, then `stdou`t is replaced with a newly opened file. Think of each redirection as a `dup2` call in C.

Answer (score 0):

According to the *Bash Reference Manual*, “2>&1 > file” directs only the standard output to “file”, because the standard error output was made a copy of the standard output; while “> file 2>&1” directs both the standard output and the standard error output to “file”.

Comment: I known this from my result. But I want a internal reason